# Unattended install of SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster fails with error - "Illegal characters in path."

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation, command-line

I am trying to build an .ini file for unattended installations of SQL Server 2008 R2. I followed this blog post to build an initial .ini file: http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008/

After cancelling the install and trying to install from the command line
(\server\store\SQL\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile="\server\store\SQL\Config.ini"), I get this error - "Illegal characters in path."

I get this error after resolving a number of simpler errors (such as paths showing up with no "\") because the created .ini file had some bugs (such as listing the path as "R:" in the .ini)

I'd like to know if anyone has been successful with installing a cluster using an ini file. Any help is appreciated.

Update:
I tried to install the cluster using the ini created from sirsql.net's powershell script. SQL does install now, but fails to bring the network name online (in the Failover Cluster Manager). All the settings look identical to our existing (functional) clusters, but a Wireshark capture shows that the new cluster is using the "realm" of the parent domain instead of the child domain (the server's domain, and the domain of all the service accounts, including the account I am using to install with). Our functional clusters show the "realm" as the child domain.
The packet that comes back from the domain controller shows this Kerberos error: `KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN`.

I'd really like to get a Failover cluster setup without having to go through the gui since we are build a couple new clusters each week. Any ideas on what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicholas Cain (@SirSQL on Twitter) published three blogs recently regarding the installation of SQL on a WIndows Failover Cluster using PowerShell to script the activity.

The first of the three blog entries may be found at http://sirsql.net/blog/2011/7/11/creating-a-clustered-sql-install-ini-file-using-powershellpa.html

The second of the three blog entries may be found at http://sirsql.net/blog/2011/7/13/creating-a-clustered-sql-install-ini-file-using-powershellpa.html

Finally, the third blog entry may be found at http://sirsql.net/blog/2011/7/18/creating-a-clustered-sql-install-ini-file-using-powershellpa.html

His approach uses PowerShell and it might give you some ideas.

Comment: I gave this a try today. It did install the bits, but failed to bring the network name online. Errors:
`Cluster network name resource 'SQL Network Name (SQLSERVERNAME)' cannot be brought online. Attempt to locate a writeable domain controller (in domain unspecified domain) in order to create a computer object associated with the resource failed for the following reason:
The RPC server is unavailable.
.`

Comment: I believe the part about the unspecified domain is the problem, although the gui for the cluster shows no difference between the network name and other clusters (it does show the domain).

Comment: I would leave a question on Nic's blog or send him a question via Twitter (@SirSQL).

Comment: I did actually leave a question for him on his, and his response helped me resolve the issue. The problem with the NETWORK NAME resolved itself once I deleted and re-created the computer object in active directory, so I believe it was related to that object being incorrectly set up.
Aside from that, the ini file produced by the blog above does work well, so I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's the perfect result! All thanks go to Robert to helping msgisme solve his/her issue! The bounty is all yours...spend it on a cake :-).